# Can you get a gold tool before getting a silver tool?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

For example, can you get a gold shovel (by buying 50 fertilizer) before getting a silver shovel (donating 15 fossils)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is entirely possible, just as it has been in earlier Animal Crossing games.

There is a difference in how to obtain the tools of different levels, but you do not have to obtain them in any certain order.